# Failed to integrate Bugzilla Testopia with Jenkins with the aid of Testopia Plugin - cannot execute any iterative build step

Tags: testing, jenkins, automation, bugzilla

I’m trying to integrate Bugzilla Testopia with Jenkins with the aid of the Testopia Plugin for Jenkins.

The general configuration is probably fine as the connection between Testopia and Jenkins is well established (Jenkins log says: ‘Connecting to Testopia to retrieve automated test cases’ and no error occurs then). However I’m unable to retrieve any information concerning Test Runs/Test Cases etc. from Testopia.

Moreover I cannot perform any of ‘Iterative Test Build Steps’. If I want to ‘Execute Shell’ in ‘Iterative Test Build Steps’ with Testopia Plugin no operation is carried out (even if I try: echo 12345 etc.). If I use ‘Single Test Build Steps‘ then shell command is executed.

My goal is to retrieve test class name from Testopia (it is stored in Testopia Test Case’s field - Automation/Scripts ) and then run maven build from Jenkins with this class name set as the parameter. Afterwards depending on the Jenkins build success or failure status I’d like to update the Test Case Status in Testopia.

How to fetch any information from Testopia into Jenkins?
Why any of ‘Iterative Test Build Steps’ is not executed?
Any clues? - Testopia Plugin site example wasn't too helpful for me.

Both Bugzilla and Jenkins are hosted on the same Ubuntu 14.04. I've got the latest stable versions of Jenkins, Bugzilla and Testopia.

Thanks in advance,
M.

EDIT:

Well this debugging does not work for me. I added a new log recorder with the 'ALL' level chosen and I cannot see any additional log neither in job's console output nor in the newly created logger output.

Maybe sth is wrong with my Testopia installation? Some more details concerning my configuration:

I've got Testopia installed on the same machine (as Jenkins) and usually I access it through: http://'ip_address'/bugzilla
 - in Testopia plugin configuration my URL to Testopia installation is: http://'ip_address'/bugzilla/xmlrpc.cgi
 - I've got only one bugzilla account - these admin's credentials I use in Jenkins
 - sometimes in Jenkins I can see a warning concerning improper reverse proxy configuraiton - maybe it has sth to do with the problem

After job execution all Testopia's fields are 0 - Run Id, Build Id etc. - which obviously indicates that no information was successfully retrieved from Testopia.

Any ideas how to check why I cannot retrieve any information from Testopia?

EDIT 2:

In the meantime I think I've found a clue in the jenkins.log file in jenkins installation directory:

Exceptions like these occur:
INFO: TESTOPIA_TEST_SUITE_3 #13 main build action completed: SUCCESS
org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException: The requested method 'TestRun.get' was not found.
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.readResponse(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:197)
...
org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException: The requested method 'TestRun.get_test_cases' was not found.
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.readResponse(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:197)

Shall I insert the full stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that plugin logs a fair amount of information, though not all of it to the build console output itself.

To debug further, you could try [adding a new log recorder](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Logging) for the logger [`jenkins.plugins.testopia`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/testopia-plugin/blob/testopia-1.3/src/main/java/jenkins/plugins/testopia/TestopiaBuilder.java) (with log level "all"), run a build, then refresh the web page for the newly-created log recorder to see the output.

You should at least see "Filtering for automated test cases" after connection, information about each test case found, and then log output for each iterative build step as it's run on each test case.

Comment: Ok, now I can see the log:

Apr 21, 2015 10:29:49 AM FINE jenkins.plugins.testopia
Filtering for automated test cases
Apr 21, 2015 10:29:51 AM INFO jenkins.plugins.testopia.TestopiaBuilder perform
Seeking test results. Using: [TestNG method name]
Apr 21, 2015 10:29:51 AM INFO jenkins.plugins.testopia.TestopiaBuilder perform
Testopia builder finished

Comment: I managed to find the stackstrace in the jenkins.log file. Have a look at the main problem description - EDIT 2.

Answer (score 0):

I got the similiar problem when I use python xmlrpc to commnicate with my bugzilla-testopia server.

I chekc the error code and find XMLRPC.pm under my bugzilla install location : "./WebService/Server/XMLRPC.pm".

I know the error was thrown by this sub function, which checks login status and forward to modules where the moduel.function must be in PUBLIC_METHODS:

```
sub handle_login {

...

if (none { $_ eq $method } $class->PUBLIC_METHODS) {
ThrowCodeError('unknown_method', { method => $full_method });
}
...
}
```

I don't know why but TestCase.get could not be found in PUBLIC_METHODS, so I just marked them as comment and then it works. You can do this quick way to make sure your client setting is correct. Then you should solve the "PUBLIC_METHODS" problem next.